# Laravel Sanctum - "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" during installation

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

When I try to install Laravel Sanctum onto my application like so:

```
composer require laravel/sanctum
```

it returns the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/sanctum ^3.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/sanctum[v3.2.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
> - laravel/sanctum[v3.2.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^9.21|^10.0 -> found illuminate/console[v9.21.0, ..., 9.x-dev,
> v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it
> conflicts with another require.
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/sanctum:*" to figure out if
> any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/sanctum:^2.1"
> if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

I'm currently on Laravel version 8.83.26. This is an old app and I upgraded with Laravel Shift a while back.

I can see from the Sanctum documentation that Sanctum comes out of the box with Laravel after Laravel 8. But for some reason my composer.json does not show Sanctum.

What should I do?

Comment: Sanctum currently requires Laravel 9. You'll need to install v2 by adding `:2.*` ( I think, or 2.15.1) to have Laravel 8 support.